# PHP: Как обрезать число так чтоб 1000 выглядило как 1

Tags: php, php7

Ну вопрос в заголовке. Например уменя число
10000, я хочу чтоб вывелось 10
Или
1000, я хочу чтоб вывелось 1
Или
255000 я хочу чтоб вывелось 255
Или 
356838 я хочу чтоб вывелось 356
Ну примеров можно много привести.
Не спрашивайте зачем, мне просто нужно, есть ли решение данной задачи, или есть уже готовая функция?
И реализовать надо это на php.
Я в php новенький, вот учусь, сейчас есть такая задача, сам не знаю как, вот решил спросить вас.
Надеюсь есть решение моей задачи.

Answer (score 1):

А, всё, я нашол решение.
По моему мнению это не совсем правильное решение.
Я использовал две функции.
Вот моё решение

```
$num = 255999;
$num_o = number_format($num, 0, ',', '.');
//result 255.999
$otvet = explode(".", $num_o);
echo $otvet[0];
//result 255
```

Мне это нужно было для сокращения баланса пользователя, например у пользователя 3 000 000 игровой валюты. 
Я таким способом вывел 3 млн.

Вот вариант функции:

```
function Socrashenie($num){
$num_o = number_format($num, 0, ',', '.');
$otvet = explode(".", $num_o);
return $otvet[0];
}

echo Socrashenie(3000000);
//result 3
```

Comment: echo intdiv( $num, 1000)